# How can you open a server on Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, hosting

I was bored this morning, so I asked my sister to join me on Minecraft PE. She did, and it worked. Then she had the idea of asking some of our friends to join us. I was thrilled with the idea, but how do I get it to work?

As far as I know, you can only join single player worlds when you're all on the same network. Right? So if that's true, how do I make a PE server?

We want to have our friends join us, it sounds fun. When we're in the same house it's kinda boring because we can chat in real.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some advanced coding or....
Download the app Multiplayer for Minecraft PE (it's on the App Store, and it's really cheap!)